# Magento - Add target to new link on toplinks

Tags: magento

I add new link to top links using

```
<block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks">
      <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
           <label>Blog</label>
           <url>/blog</url>
           <title>Blog</title>
           <prepare/>
           <urlParams/>
           <position>1</position>
      </action>
</block>
```

It works properly. 
I want to add `target="_blank"` to this link.

Is there any way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks">
      <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
           <label>Blog</label>
           <url>/blog</url>
           <title>Blog</title>
           <prepare/>
           <urlParams/>
           <position>1</position>
           <aParams>
                    <target>_blank</target>
           </aParams>
      </action>
</block>
```

Your welcome! Feel free to have a look at the addLink() method at any time!

Comment: Thank you. It works.
For further informations, if you set `aParams`, you have to set `liParams` as well, or at least you must have `liParams` tag. Otherwise, `aParams`'s value will be taken as `liParams`.